# Structure morphisms of projective spaces commute

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Suppose we have a ring morphism $B\rightarrow A$, and the related map $B[x_0,...,x_n]\rightarrow A[x_0,...,x_n]$. How do I show that the induced maps yield a commutative diagram:

$$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
\mathbb{P}^n_A @>>> \mathbb{P}^n_B \\
@VVV @VVV \\
\operatorname{Spec}A @>>>\operatorname{Spec}B
\end{CD}$$

I've already done it manually, so I want to know if there's a cleaner way that I'm missing.

**My attempt at a "clean" solution:**

I tried taking the $\operatorname{Proj}$ of some suitable diagram:
$$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
A[x_0,...,x_n] @<<< B[x_0,...,x_n] \\
@AAA @AAA \\
A[X] @<<< B[X]
\end{CD}$$
but I couldn't find a morphism $A[X]\rightarrow A[x_0,...,x_n]$ (and proved there is none, I believe)  that would induce the structure morphisms on $\mathbb{P}^n_A$.

Comment: What do you mean by $A[X]$ and $B[X]$? You should just have $B \to A$ along the bottom, and the vertical arrows are the inclusions $A \to A[x_0,...,x_n]$.

Comment: @TabesBridges $A[X]$ is the polynomial ring in one variable. I was thinking of $\operatorname{Proj} A[X] \cong \operatorname{Spec} A$. 

If I just had $B\rightarrow A$ on the bottom, I would need to take $\operatorname{Proj}$ on top and $\operatorname{Spec}$ on the bottom. I'm not sure how this would cleanly give us a commutative diagram.

Comment: Ahhhh right right right...you have a good point then; this approach may be hopeless (since not all morphisms of projective schemes come from a morphism of graded rings).